# put latitude and longitude via graph api in facebook event

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dictionary, facebook-php-sdk, latitude-longitude, facebook-events

I would like to create an Event on my FB fan page via PHP SDK Graph API V.3.1.1, by defining latitude and longitude.

Here is my request :

```
$event_param = array(
    "access_token" => $access_token,
    "name" => $name,
    "description"=>$description,
    "start_time" => $start_time,
    "end_time" => $end_time,
    "street"=> $street,
    "city"=>$city,
    "country"=>$country,
    "latitude" => $lat,
    "longitude" => $lng,
    "updated_time"=>time()
);
$facebook->api('/'.$pageID.'/events', "POST", $event_param);
```

The event is created but when I check the event on http://graph.facebook.com/my_event_id, I can see that neither latitude or longitude are defined.
And when I display the event on my Facebook page, there is not map to show the location of the event.
I have tried to get an placeID before creating the event, but that seems to work only for centers of cities, not for precise address. Maybe I've missed something...

Any ideas is very welcomed ! Thanks

Nobody has a solution for that ? Is this an issue ?

---

Edit :
An issue has been created on this last January. It seems that nothing moves on this question since:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/173095916131752

Comment: Let us know if you have any news, right now it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's supposed to take a venue property rather than just passing latitude and longitude. Check out the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/).

So instead of an array with lat/lon, make that

```
....
"venue" => array ("latitude" => $lat, "longitude" => $lon),
....
```

Comment: Hi Jordan. According to docs, it is supposed to work as you've written, but it doesn't. By searching on the web, I found that also "street", "city".. fields have to be initialized outside "venue" field. Indeed "street", "city".. are well defined via my request above. That is in contradiction with docs because all these fields are supposed to be initialized in "venue" array. Something goes wrong...

Comment: Can you post your updated code? "venue" is supposed to be a nested array within $event_param.

Comment: I have tried that: $event_param = array(
    "access_token" => $access_token,
    "name" =>$name,
 "description"=>$description,
    "start_time" => $start_time, "end_time"=>$end-time,
   "updated_time"=>time(),
 
 "venue"=> array ("street"=>$street,
 "city"=>$city,
 "state"=>$state,
 "country"=>$country,"latitude" => $lat, "longitude" => $lng)
);

Comment: I have also tried with $event_param = array( "access_token" => $access_token, "name" =>$name, "description"=>$description, "start_time" => $start_time, "end_time"=>$end-time, "updated_time"=>time(), "street"=>$street, "city"=>$city, "state"=>$state, "country"=>$country,"venue"=> array ("latitude" => $lat, "longitude" => $lng) );